# Windows takes so long at first login to CentOS SAMBA DC

Tags: windows, centos, samba, redhat-enterprise-linux, domain

I set up SAMBA 4.7.0 DC on CentOS 7.4 by referring to this [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/samba-4-domain-controller-installation-on-centos/) . Everything went smooth as it says. I set up DNS Backend as SAMBA_INTERNAL and DNS Forwarder as 8.8.4.4 even though I didn't configure any DNS settings or configurations before the SAMBA setup.

After finishing the SAMBA set up, I created some administrative users. I put the Windows client which is in the same LAN under the SAMBA Domain. Everything goes well and a restart processed.

I tried to login with domain username and password. A WELCOME circle keeps winding for about 8 minutes and the following error occured.

> The Group Policy Client service failed the sing-in. 
>    The universal unique identifier (UUID) type is not supported.

I clicked OK and tried the same process again. This time, Windows logged in just as normal and the logging in goes well untill another new account logins.

I don't like to wait for more than 8 minutes after new logins. How can I fix please.

Please edit this post for better explanation as my English is bad AF.

Comment: It would help to have complete samba log, which windows are you using, are the windows registered to the domain, what kind of profiles do you use in your windows?

Comment: Windows is 8.1 Pro. The Windows was registered successfully to the domain. I used domain admin profile in Windows. I will upload the log.

Comment: I see there is a bug in the profile format.  See my answer.

Comment: Sorry dude. I was on the trip and still haven't tried your answer. I will let you know if it helps me or not :) Appreciate your help, @tukan

Comment: No pro, dude.  Try it out and tell us the result.

Answer (score 0):

Ah Windows 8.1.  There is one bug [#2890783](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2890783/incompatibility-between-windows-8-1-roaming-user-profiles-and-those-in) called - *Incompatibility between Windows 8.1 roaming user profiles and those in earlier versions of Windows*

**The issue is caused by:** Roaming user profiles on win8 or win2012 being incompatible with roaming user profiles in other versions of Windows.

To quote the Microsoft for solution:

> ### Resolution
>
> Update information To prevent this issue, before you deploy
>   roaming, mandatory, super-mandatory, or domain default profiles in an
>   environment where users will be using earlier versions of the
>   operating system in addition to Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2,
>   follow these steps:
>
> 1. Install update rollup 2887595. For more information about how to
>      obtain this update rollup package, click the following article
>      number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>      2887595 Windows RT 8.1, Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2 update rollup: November 2013
> 2. Create a new registry entry by following the steps that are described in the "Registry information" section.
> 3. Restart the computer.
>
>    **Note:** If the roaming user profile is corrupted, you cannot use this
>      update to resolve the issue. To recover from profile corruption,
>      restore the roaming user profile from a backup.
>
> ### Registry information
>
> **Important** This section, method, or task contains steps that tell you
>   how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if
>   you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you
>   follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the
>   registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a
>   problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore
>   the registry, click the following article number to view the article
>   in the Microsoft Knowledge Base: 322756 How to back up and restore the
>   registry in Windows After you apply this update, you must create a
>   registry key before you restart the computer.
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search. Or,
>      if you are using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the
>      screen, and then click Search.
> 2. In the search box, type regedit, and then tap or click regedit.
>      note: UAC If you are prompted to enter an administrator password, type the password. If you are prompted to provide confirmation, provide
>      confirmation.
> 3. Locate and then tap or click the following registry subkey:
>      **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlset\Services\ProfSvc\Parameters`**
> 4. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then tap or click DWORD Value.
> 5. Type UseProfilePathExtensionVersion.
> 6. Press and hold or right-click UseProfilePathExtensionVersion, and
>      then tap or click Modify.
> 7. In the Value data box, type 1, and then tap or click OK.
> 8. Exit Registry Editor.
>
> After you configure the **UseProfilePathExtensionVersion** registry entry,
>   you have to restart the computer. Then, Windows 8.1 creates a user
>   profile and appends the suffix ".v4" to the profile folder name to
>   differentiate it from version 2 of the profile in Windows 7 and
>   version 3 of the profile in Windows 8. Windows 8.1-based computers
>   that have update rollup 2887595 installed and the
>   **UseProfilePathExtensionVersion** registry entry configured use version 4
>   of the profile.
>
> Notes
>
> - You can disable this feature by setting the value of the UseProfilePathExtensionVersion registry entry to 0. However, user
>     profile corruption occurs if you continue to mix roaming user profiles
>     from Windows 8.1-based computers with those from other operating
>     systems.
> - You can use the Group Policy Preference (GPP) Computer Configuration Registry Preference item to populate the registry key
>     on
>     multiple computers. For more information about this, go to the
>     following Microsoft website:
>     Configure a registry item
> - You can safely apply this update on all operating systems. If these profile types are not being used, the registry setting is
>     ignored.